# References same model field many many times

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, model, associations

I have a Lesson model that contains about 50 fields that all reference a Grade model.  The grades model has a simple list 0-8 that is used as a lessons graded value.

Is there a way to avoid filling up my model with 50 lines of:

```
 belongs_to :walking, :class => 'Grade'
 belongs_to :running, :class => 'Grade'   
 belongs_to :crawling, :class => 'Grade' 
 ...
```

postgres database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
fields = %w[walking running crawling] # list all 50 of them here
fields.each { |field| belongs_to field.to_sym, :class => 'Grade' }
```

That will at least save you from having to write all the lines out, but you still need to list the names of the associations (walking, running, crawling, etc.) for it to work (as I've indicated above).

Comment: Although I didn't test it, I suspect you don't even need that `to_sym` in there.